# programmatically change the name of which UIImageView

Tags: ios5

In my IB I already have 5 UIImageViews with an image in each of them.  UIImageViews are called blue1, blue2,.... blue5.

In my code I'm trying to add a pan gesture recognizer and then add them to an array.

How could i programmatically change the name of which UIImageView?

I tried making a string first and then casting it to UIImageView in the addObject step but that didn't work.

I tihnk i have to make it UIImageView in the first line below but then how could i do something like what i did below with NSString `stringWithFormat:@"blue%d", numberOfSetUpTurns+1]`

```
NSString * currentPlayer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blue%d", numberOfSetUpTurns+1];        

[playerOneArr addObject: (UIImageView *)currentPlayer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code that you have now, you are trying to cast a string into a UIImageView, which will not work.

You can perhaps create an NSMutableDictionary, to the dictionary you can do something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict addObject: someUIImageView forKey:currentPlayer];
```

This way when you want to retrieve the imageView you can just call

```
[playerOneArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:currentPlayer]];
```

I hope I understood your question and I hope this helps!